# Prove by the definition of convergence that the sequence an converges to 1.

Tags: sequences-and-series, logic, convergence-divergence

I know the definition of convergence as a sequence an approaches the limit if for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $N \in\mathbb N$ such that $|a_n - L| \lt \epsilon$.

How do I prove with this definition that the sequence $a_n = (\sqrt a + \frac{a}{n})$ converges to $1$?

I know using the $|a_n - L| \lt \epsilon$ yields $|(\sqrt n+\frac1n) - 1| \lt \epsilon$  but how do I simplify this so that I can write the proof for it?

Comment: Note: The set membership sign $\in$ is **not the same** as the Greek letter epsilon, $\varepsilon$ or $\epsilon$. You want the latter here.

Comment: Also, as far as I can see, your sequence will converge to $\sqrt a$. We have $|a_n-\sqrt a|=|\frac an|=\frac an$ which becomes arbitrarily close to $0$ as $n$ gets large.

Comment: Even if you meant $\sqrt{a+\frac an}$ that doesn't change it. $a+\frac an$ converges to $a$, and the square root function is continuous at $a$, so the limit is still $\sqrt a$.